# Insert parameter data from one output into another

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, office365

This is directed towards Exchange/Office 365 powershell but can apply for other types as well.

If i have a list of users for example, and I use `UserPrincipalName` for their identity - now in all my scripts I can pull data using `UserPrincipalName` for the identity, but in  most `UserPrincipalName` isn't actually an exportable value. So, if you take my two examples below I can pull data in both using `UserPrincipalName` for the identity, but in the 2nd one the ouput would be blank.

How can I insert for example the identity value `UserPrincipalName` into the 2nd. This would apply for more than the two scripts mentioned below.

```
$CSV |  foreach {
  Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName
} | select userprincipalname, server |out-gridview
```

Example output:

> `UPN@something.com, server101`

```
$csv | ForEach {
  Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Identity:$_.UserPrincipalName
} | select  DeviceFriendlyName,UserPrincipalName |out-gridview
```

Example output:

> `2nd: DeviceIOS4,-`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Exchange at hand, but most likely the objects returned by `Get-Mailbox` do have a `UserPrincipalName` property, while the objects returned by `Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics` don't. To preserve the UPN in the output of the second script, you can do something like this:

```
$csv | ForEach {
  $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
  Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Identity:$upn
} | select  DeviceFriendlyName,@{n='UserPrincipalName';e={$upn}} |out-gridview
```